# How to pull from a local repository on another computer?

Tags: git

I have create a repository on my laptop, how can I clone the repository in my laptop to my desktop? I have already created a shared folder where my repository is located. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Shared folder" suggests that you're using Windows.

If your shared folder is available as a mapped network drive, say `z:`, then you can just clone as if it were a local repository:

```
git clone file://z:/path/to/repository.git
```

(I'm not sure about slashes vs. backslashes here; currently on Linux so I can't test it.)

Your question title asks about pulling, not cloning. But pulling should be trivial once you've got the clone.